# jquery.mobile collapsible parent & child expanded with filter

Tags: jquery, css

I have made a codepen example of the parent & child collapsible content I am using from the jquery.mobile library.
It works as I require in terms of the filtering.
And it loads initially with the contents collapsed as I wish.

However it does not expand the content as the filter search is applied.
The results are filtered, but you need to manually [click] expand them to see the results, which is not ideal. Especially when results may return from more than one collapsible content section.

Here is the example code demo:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LRqBaa

And here is the html from that example:

```
<div data-role="page" id="myfilter">
```

```
I would like the relevent below collapsed contents to expand when the filter is used.
For example, filtering for 'liz' would show just the 'Animals' collapsible be expanded with just the one result under it - Lizard

<h2>Collapsible set with search</h2>
<form>
<input data-type="search" id="searchForCollapsibleSetChildren">
</form>
<div data-role="collapsible-set" data-filter="true" data-children="> div, > div div ul li" data-inset="true" id="collapsiblesetForFilterChildren" data-input="#searchForCollapsibleSetChildren">
    <div data-role="collapsible" data-filtertext="Animals Cats Dogs Lizards snakes">
        <h3>Animals</h3>
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="false">
            <li data-filtertext="Animals Cats">Cats</li>
            <li data-filtertext="Animals Dogs">Dogs</li>
            <li data-filtertext="Animals Lizards">Lizards</li>
            <li data-filtertext="Animals Snakes">Snakes</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div data-role="collapsible" data-filtertext="Cars Acura Audi BMW Cadillac">
        <h3>Cars</h3>
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="false">
            <li data-filtertext="Cars Acura">Acura</li>
            <li data-filtertext="Cars Audi">Audi</li>
            <li data-filtertext="Cars BMW">BMW</li>
            <li data-filtertext="Cars Cadillac">Cadillac</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div data-role="collapsible" data-filtertext="Planets Earth Jupiter Mars Mercury">
        <h3>Planets</h3>
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="false">
            <li data-filtertext="Planets Acura">Earth</li>
            <li data-filtertext="Planets Jupiter">Jupiter</li>
            <li data-filtertext="Planets Mars">Mars</li>
            <li data-filtertext="Planets Mercury">Mercury</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'd be grateful for any expert advice, as not sure how to achieve this and couldn't find anything within the libraries example pages.
Thanks

**EDIT:**

I have just found another jsfiddle, which I did not create, but is almost what I require.
Please see this example:
https://jsfiddle.net/j5krxota/1/

There, you will notice that it does actually expand the sections as results to the filter are found, which is what I want.
I would prefer it though, if:

- Did *not* expand the first collapsible [animals] when the filter is cleared.. if you filter for 'ca' it catches the result 'cats', but then when you clear the filter, the 'animals' section remains expanded. I'd like it to close again when filter cleared.
- Something seems incorrect with the filter in some instances. For example, filter 'ju' returns the result 'jupiter' from the 'planets' expandable section. Which is correct.
  But when you filter 'ca' the 'cadillac' result from the 'cars' section should return, but the 'cars' section does not expand... only the 'animals' one does, due to the detection of 'cats'.

Apologies for asking a few things here, but it's beyond me why it filters like that, seems one section expands the results [planets] while another doesn't [cars]. I've no idea why, and wouldn't a clue how to fix this with js myself.
Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Please apply below script to achieve your requirement :

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", "#myfilter", function(){
    $("#collapsiblesetForFilterChildren").on( "filterablefilter", function( event, ui ) {
        ui.items.each(function( index ) {
              $(this).collapsible("option", "collapsed", $(this).hasClass("ui-screen-hidden")).removeClass("ui-screen-hidden");

        });
    });
});
```

Note : To apply above js I have made some changes in your HTML structure as well.

Please go through working demo : http://jsfiddle.net/2Snbq/29/

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't finished writing my reply there ^     ...Your example is nearly as I need it, in that it now does expand, but it now shows all the items within that collapsible, rather than just the results.   So typing filter for 'liz' does expand the 'Animals', but it no longer only shows the 'lizard' and instead it shows also 'cats' 'dogs' etc..    Could it work like yours, but only show relevant results rather than everything within that expandable?   Thanks